# ReactNative: How to store API response in Sqlite database

Tags: react-redux, react-native, redux-thunk

Hello I want to create an application in react-native which will fetch user transaction history from server and show it to user, User can change the status of transaction and the update should be sent to server.

But this functionality should work even without network except first time. So when user opens application transaction history will be fetched from Server and should be saved in local db to ensure user can see the list even when network is not available. User can update status of local transaction and once the network is available updated transaction details should be sent to server.

Till now I am able to fetch transaction from server and post update to server and looking for industry wide standard solution for data persistence in react-native.

To summaries my question...

1) What is the best way to store Json response locally and support `CURD` operation? (Like `SQLiteOpenHelper`, `ContentProvider` in android)

2) Should work seamlessly on Android and iOs devices.

3) Is there any library available to efficiently handle this use case?

Comment: If you are interested in library then check it, https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: Why not use the onboard `AsyncStorage` of react-native? It uses sqlite under the hood and it's api is quite simple to understand.

1) plays well with JSON (no crud operations though)
2) works on both iOS and Android
3) It's built in :D

Hope this helps